# Unable to set selected value of second Dropdown from selection on click event In angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have two DropDown in code. I'm binding its value using data-ng-options on Option. I want to Set the selected value of 2nd dropdown according to first is select.

This is My code.

```
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedOption" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default" ng-change="onselectClick()">                                                   </select>
<!-- Second dropdown -->
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in secondoptions track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedSecondOption" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default">
</select>
```

Js

```
 $scope.options = [
     {"id" : "Please Select","name" : "Please Select"}, 
     {"id" : "1","name" : "1"}, 
     {"id" : "2","name" : "2"}, 
     {"id" : "3","name" : "3"}, 
     {"id" : "4","name" : "4"}];
    $scope.secondoptions = [
     {"id" : "Please Select","name" : "Please Select"}, 
     {"id" : "1","name" : "1"}, 
     {"id" : "2","name" : "2"}, 
     {"id" : "3","name" : "3"}, 
     {"id" : "4","name" : "4"}];
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options [0];
    $scope.selectedSecondOption = $scope.secondoptions [0];

    $scope.onselectClick = function() {
    $scope.selectedSecondOption = $scope.secondoptions[3];
    }
```

I have referred following URLs:

1. [Unable to set selected value in angularjs dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465597/unable-to-set-selected-value-in-angularjs-dropdown)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/dCFd2/

**If anyone knows the solution, please help me.**

**Thanks.**

Comment: you can pass first selected option id to your assign value in onclick function.

Comment: @sahil0021: Thanks for your comment on this. I have passed it and also pass this: {"id" : "1","name" : "1"}, but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening just because of the Bootstrap UI. Following code works for me.

```
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in secondoptions track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedSecondOption" class="selectpicker secondselect" data-style="btn-default"> </select>  

$('.secondselect').selectpicker('val',"3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to get something like this?

```js
var app = angular.module("App", [])
app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl($scope){
   $scope.options = [
     {"id" : "0","name" : "Please Select"}, 
     {"id" : "1","name" : "1"}, 
     {"id" : "2","name" : "2"}, 
     {"id" : "3","name" : "3"}, 
     {"id" : "4","name" : "4"}
  ];
  $scope.secondoptions = [
    {"id" : "0","name" : "Please Select"}, 
    {"id" : "1","name" : "1"}, 
    {"id" : "2","name" : "2"}, 
    {"id" : "3","name" : "3"}, 
    {"id" : "4","name" : "4"}
  ];
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];
    $scope.selectedSecondOption = $scope.secondoptions[0];

    $scope.onselectClick = function() {
     $scope.selectedSecondOption = $scope.secondoptions[$scope.selectedOption.id];
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedOption" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default" ng-change="onselectClick()">                             </select>
  <!-- Second dropdown -->
  <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in secondoptions track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedSecondOption" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default">
  </select>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I simply need to select 2nd drop-down data but still it didn't work for me. I think i used bootstrap-ui that's why it happens.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to call $scope.$digest() after change inputs value

Comment: Thanks for the time buddy. That is happening just because of the Bootstrap UI. Following code works for me. 

`<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in secondoptions track by o.id" data-ng-model="selectedSecondOption" class="selectpicker secondselect" data-style="btn-default">
</select>

$('.secondselect').selectpicker('val',"3"); `